# Implement notification from Application Service

Tags: c#, notifications, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to implement "Notification System" from my Application Service.

I would like to alert a user using a toast via `abp.notify.info()` when the required processing (managed by Application Service) has been successfully completed.

Server side:

```
public async Task<bool> EsitoAllestimento(EsitoAllestimento data)
{
    await _notiticationPublisher.PublishAsync(
        "message"",
        null,
        null,
        NotificationSeverity.Info
    );
}
```

Client side:

```js
abp.event.on('abp.notifications.received', function (userNotification) {
    abp.notify.info('message', 'text');
});
```

**UPDATE**

At the moment, I use a different strategy based on the use of email messages from application layer.

In fact, `EsitoAllestimento` (WebApi method) is invoked by an external application to update some data in the web application (and informs the connected user of the processing result).

Now I'm planning to use SignalR communication, because email communication sometimes fails.

I have defined the hub class like [ABP's SignalR Integration example](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/v2.3.0/SignalR-Integration) and everything works fine, except communication from SERVER to CLIENT.

How can I use `myChatHub` at the Application layer or WebApi layer ?

Comment: You need to implement `SignalR` to send real-time notifications.

Comment: Read https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-Integration

Comment: Ni @aaron, I've implemented another strategy but I'm considering using of SignalR for a future release ;)

Comment: actually i'm unable to send message from server to client using SignalR communication

Comment: @Saro Is this resolved?

Comment: @aaron yes, but with different strategy

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [Notification System](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System):

> There are two ways of sending notifications to users:
>
> - The user **subscribes** to a specific notification type. Then we **publish** a notification of this type which is delivered to all **subscribed** users. This is the **pub/sub** model.
> - We can **directly send** a notification to **target user(s)**.

The **Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR** package implements [`IRealTimeNotifier`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System#real-time-notifications) to send real-time notifications to clients automatically, so you don't have to implement and call a custom `Hub` .

In your case, you should specify the target user.

- The first argument is the [notification name](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System#notification-definitions).
- The second argument is where your `"message"` should go.
- The `userIds` argument is where you should specify the target user.

For example, this shows how to send a message to the default tenant admin and the host admin:

```cs
var message = "message";

var defaultTenantAdmin = new UserIdentifier(1, 2);
var hostAdmin = new UserIdentifier(null, 1);

await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(
    "App.SimpleMessage",
    new MessageNotificationData(message),
    severity: NotificationSeverity.Info,
    userIds: new[] { defaultTenantAdmin, hostAdmin }
);
```

You don't have to implement the event listener on the client side as `abp.notify.info` is the default.